# What's the shortcut for showing a function parameters in NetBeans?

Tags: java, function, netbeans, parameters, shortcut

Example:

```
void Sandwich(string ham, string bread, int cheese){
...do stuff...
};
```

When I type Sandwich(, I need to see what are the required parameters.
How can I do that?

Comment: ctrl + space maybe, or ctrl+ shift + space?

Answer (score 8):

For non-Mac, you can use `Ctrl+P`. For Mac, you can use `Command + P`

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the **Auto Popup Code Completion** option in **Tools > Options > Editor > Code Completion**.

Enable it for **All Languages**, the selection for individual languages does not seem to work, not for PHP at least. It seems there's a bug with the All Languages deactivation taking precedence over the rest of the languages.